# How to find out if the current frame has OS level focus in Emacs

Tags: emacs

I've started using ERC and bitlbee to manage my chat sessions in Emacs. It's working out splendidly, with one small missing feature - alerts when Emacs doesn't have focus.

Ideally I'd have an OS level alert (Growl or whatever) when I'm sent a message and either the chat buffer is buried or Emacs itself is not the application with input focus. I've got the first bit working fine, but I'll be buggered if I can find a way of determining if Emacs itself has input focus.

The nearest I could find is frame-visible-p, but that only tells you if the frame is minimised or not.

Any help much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try polling, on a timer, and checking for a `switch-frame` event.  Might or might not work.  See the Elisp manual, node `Focus Events`.

Comment: Mm, I think that only fires an event when you change to another emacs frame, rather than another window entirely. Certainly, that's what a quick test showed, and it seems to indicate as much in the docs. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

You can run an external command. This gets you the name of the active window with xdotool

```
(defun get-active-window-title ()
  (let ((command-result
         (shell-command-to-string
          (concat "xdotool getwindowname "
                  (shell-command-to-string
                   "xdotool getactivewindow")))))
    (substring
     command-result
     0 (1- (length command-result)))))
```